# Kendo UI Scheduler

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Implantei o template Kendo UI Scheduler (agenda/calendário) no meu projeto ASP.NET MVC, mas estou com problemas nos pop-ups do mesmo.
Por exemplo: O popup não se fecha sozinho quando você clica no "save", por exemplo. Ou quando eu clico no "X" pra fechar o popup e o evento é excluído.

Esses são bugs normais ?

Obs.: Não há erros nos controllers.

Segue trecho do código javascript:

```
<div id="scheduler"></div>
<script>

    $("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
        date: new Date(),
        currentTimeMarker: {
            updateInterval: 100
        },
        showWorkHours: true,
        editable: {
            confirmation: false
        },
        views: [
            "day", "week", "workWeek", { type: "month", selected: true },"agenda"
        ],
        allDayEventTemplate: $("#event-template").html(),
        //edit: editEvent,
        //editable: {
        //    template: $("#editor").html()
        //},
        timezone:"Etc/UTC",
        dataSource:
        {
            batch: true,
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/Agendas/Get",
                    dataType: "json" 
                },
                update: {
                    url: "/Agendas/Update",
                    dataType: "json"
                },
                create: {
                    url: "/Agendas/Create",
                    dataType: "json"
                },
                destroy: {
                    url: "/Agendas/Delete",
                    dataType: "json"
                },
                parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                    if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                        return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                    }
                }
            },


                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "taskId",
                        fields: {
                            taskId: { from:"TaskID", type: "number" },
                            title: { field: "Title", defaultValue: "No title", validation: { required: true } },
                            start: { type: "date", field: "Start" },
                            end: { type: "date", field: "End" },
                            description: { field: "Description" },
                            recurrenceId: { from: "RecurrenceID" },
                            recurrenceRule: { from: "RecurrenceRule" },
                            recurrenceException: { from: "RecurrenceException" },
                            isAllDay: { type: "boolean", from: "IsAllDay" },
                            ownersID: { from: "OwnersID", defaultValue: [@Model.Codigo, 1] }
                        }
                    }
                }

        },

        resources: [
            {
                field: "ownersID",
                title: "Responsável",
                dataSource: [
                    { text: "nome1", value: 1, color: "#ff0000" },
                    { text: "nome2", value: 2, color: "#ff9900" },
                    { text: "nome3", value: 3, color: "#0000cc" },
                    { text: "nome4", value: 11, color: "#009900" },
                    { text: "nome5", value: 4, color: "#51a0ed" },
                    { text: "nome6", value: 6, color: "#56ca85" },
                    { text: "nome7", value: 5, color: "#f8a398" },
                    { text: "nome8", value: 8, color: "#cc3300" }
                ],
                multiple: true
            }
        ]
    });
```

Obs.: Estou usando os popups do próprio Kendo Scheduler.

Comment: Pode colocar um trecho do seu código na pergunta?

Comment: pronto, ta na mão ...

Comment: Acho que não é aí o problema. Você tem também o código da popup do event?

Comment: Então .. não, só peguei o exemplo da propria documentação do kendo scheduler, que já vem com os eventos ...

Comment: Preciso que você edite sua pergunta e coloque o link pra eu simular aqui. O meu funcionou.

Comment: link do que ? :/ .. Desculpe pela minha ignorancia, sou novo por aqui

Comment: Link do exemplo da documentação do Kendo. Não sei se estamos olhando o mesmo exemplo.

Comment: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/scheduler 
usei o módulo de datasource

Answer (score 1):

O Kendo UI não é compatível com diversas versões do jQuery. Eventos assim mostram que alguma coisa nos eventos do jQuery está quebrada.

[Verifique aqui qual versão você pode usar](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/installation/prerequisites#supported-jquery-versions). Trave seu `packages.config` para usar apenas a versão do jQuery compatível:

```
<package id="jQuery" version="1.12.3" targetFramework="net452" allowedVersions="[1.12.3]" />
```